# NoClassDefFoundError error on Mac with NetBeans

Tags: java

I am getting a `NoClassDefFoundError` error when I run my program. Here is the stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ex7/Ex7
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ex7.Ex7
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Java Result: 1
```

How do I fix this? I'm on a Mac and running NetBeans.

Comment: A bit more context would be good, like what project type did you create in Netbeans, are you sure there's a package ex7 containing a class Ex7 in the project, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It seems class `Ex7`class from package `ex7` isn't in classpath. recheck the class try clean build

Comment: How do you check the class path in Netbeans Macintosh OS

Comment: well when you use IDE it is less likely the case, try a shot with clean and build also see the class compiles fine.